# como passar uma string php por um parametro java script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou criando um contador de click no link desta maneira:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return chamarPhpAjax();"></a>
```

Que ao clicar no link chama a função:

```
function chamarPhpAjax() {
    var so = "";
    var name = "";
   $.ajax({
      url:'/assets/classes/meuajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { 'so': so, 'name': name }
  });  

  return false;
}
```

Pelo Ajax, os dados são enviados via POST para a página "meuajax.php":

```
<?php
function testeOnclick() {
    $so = $_POST['so'];
    $name = $_POST['name'] ;

     include_once "../config/Config.inc.php";

      $pdo->query("UPDATE '$so' SET downloads = downloads +1 WHERE name = '$name' ");

}
testeOnclick();
?>
```

O problema é que não consigo receber por parâmetro os dados para colocar na `var so = ""; var name = "";` do Ajax. Como passo os dados no `onclick`, ficando mais ou menos assim:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return chamarPhpAjax(<?php $dados->so;?> , <?php $dados->name;?> );"></a>
```

E receber no Ajax esses parâmetros?

Comment: Pode reformular sua pergunta, excluindo os snippets que não funcionam no contexto?

Comment: ok vou tentar da uma explicação melhor

Answer (score -1):

resolvi dessa maneira

```js
function chamarPhpAjax() {
   
    var so  = $('.icon-dwl').attr('data-so');
    var name = $('.icon-dwl').attr('data-name');
   $.ajax({
      url:'/assets/classes/meuajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { 'so': so, 'name': name }
  });  

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Você esta passando os parâmetros em

```
<a href="#" onclick="return chamarPhpAjax(<?php $dados->so;?> , <?php $dados->name;?> );"></a>
```

mas sua função

```
function chamarPhpAjax() {

 var so = "";
 var name = "";
 $.ajax({

      url:'/assets/classes/meuajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { 'so': so, 'name': name }
 });

return false; }
```

Não esta pegando parâmetro nenhum.Tente colocar

```
 function chamarPhpAjax(so,name) {

 var so = so;
 var name = name;
 $.ajax({

      url:'/assets/classes/meuajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: { 'so': so, 'name': name }
 });

return false; }
```